# Self Sizing CollectionView cell not work properly after reload data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am creating a collectionView that can have multiple sections with a self-sizing cell.

it works nicely on the initial layout. but after reload, I encounter three problem

1. Scrolling become choppy
2. cell size changed and cell overlap with each other
3. content offset changed after reload data

here is ViewController code

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var isLayout = false
     let dataSource: [Model] = [
        Model(title: "The domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia mailing list.[17] Wikipedia's policy of [24] was codified in its first few months. Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated independently of Nupedia.[17] Originally, Bomis intended to make Wikipedia a business for profit.[25]"),
        Model(title: "Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated independently of Nupedia.[17] Originally, Bomis intended to make Wikipedia a business for profit.[25]"),
        Model(title: "of Nupedia.[17] Originally, Bomis intended to make Wikipedia a business for profit.[25]"),
        Model(title: "The domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13,"),
        Model(title: "The domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13,"),
        Model(title: "Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated independently of Nupedia.[17] Originally, Bomis intended to make Wikipedia a business for profit.[25]"),
        Model(title: "as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia mailing list.[17] "),
        Model(title: " 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia mailing list.[17] Wikipedia's policy of [24] was codified in its first few months. Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated independently"),
        Model(title: "2001[21] and January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia mailing list.[17] Wikipedia's policy of [24] was codified in "),
        Model(title: "y 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia mailing list.[17] Wikipedia's policy of [24] was codified in its first few months. Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated indepe"),
        Model(title: "of Nupedia.[17] Originally, Bomis intended to make Wikipedia a business for profit.[25]"),
        Model(title: "domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a singl"),
        Model(title: "s first few months. Otherwise, there were relatively few rules initially and Wikipedia operated independently "),
        Model(title: "s first few months. Otherwise,"),
        Model(title: "i as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the "),
        Model(title: "January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a singl"),
        Model(title: "Eespectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia m"),
        Model(title: "domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a singl"),
        Model(title: "anguage edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia m"),
        Model(title: "anguage edition at www.wiki"),
        Model(title: "domains"),
        Model(title: "domains wikipedia.com and wikipedia.org were registered on January 12, 2001[21] and January 13, 2001[22] respectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a singl"),
        Model(title: "Eespectively, and Wikipedia was launched on January 15, 2001,[13] as a single English-language edition at www.wikipedia.com,[23] and announced by Sanger on the Nupedia m"),
        Model(title: "domains")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if !isLayout {
            if  let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                  collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize =  CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2, height: 100)
                  collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
              }
            isLayout = true
        }

    }

    @IBAction func reloadData(sender: UIButton) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: - Collection view delegate and data source methods

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionViewCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = dataSource[indexPath.item].title
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        if indexPath.section % 2 == 0 {
            cell.maxWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/2
        } else {
            cell.maxWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

below is the collectionView cell code

import UIKit

```
class TestCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet private var maxWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! {
        didSet {
            maxWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        }
    }

    var maxWidth: CGFloat? = nil {
        didSet {
            guard let maxWidth = maxWidth else {
                return
            }
            maxWidthConstraint.isActive = true
            maxWidthConstraint.constant = maxWidth
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
            contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
            ])
    }
}
```

CollectionView cell contains only one label

1. label(leading,trailing,top,bottom) equal to collectionview
   cell(leading,trailing,top,bottom)
2. label width equal to 50 with 900
   priority

[image]

Here is the demo source code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_LhIsTPRSW19UKMQPJiroAZ8KO4gciW/view

Comment: Do you need the cell's dimension to be based on the length of the text?

Comment: yes, I want cell height dynamic. it already worked on the given demo. but after reloading collectionview some problems occurred That I already mention in the Question.

Comment: was a solution found for this?

Comment: @Glitch_Znab no I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Properly set your collection view:

```swift
 let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //Specify the scroll direction
 collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
 collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

2. Set the space you want tone between each section:

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
```

3. Set some space between the cells:

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }
```

4. Set a custom width and height for each of your cell. We'll use two helper functions to achieve what you need:

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout:
                            UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return calculateWidth(inString: dataSource[indexPath.row].title)+30, height: calculateHeight(inString: dataSource[indexPath.row].title)+30 )

//Calling these functions will return the dimension of each element in your array 
//Here I add 30 points because that's what I liked it better. If you don't like it, delete that part.
    }
```

This is the function you'll use to calculate the width of the text you'll put inside of each collection view cell. It returns its width.

```swift
    func calculateWidth(inString:String) -> CGFloat{
        let messageString = inString
        let attributes : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue:
                                                                                    NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:
                                                                                                                                                universalFont(size: 15))] //If you use a different font/dimension, change it here
        
        let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
        let rect : CGRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 222.0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                          options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        
        let requredSize:CGRect = rect
        return requredSize.width
    }
```

This is the function you'll use to calculate the height of the text you'll put inside of each collection view cell. It returns its height.

```swift
    func calculateHeight(inString:String) -> CGFloat{
        let messageString = inString
        let attributes : [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue:
                                                                                    NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:
                                                                                                                                                universalFont(size: 15))] //If you use a different font/dimension, change it here
        
        let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
        let rect : CGRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 222.0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                          options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        
        let requredSize:CGRect = rect
        return requredSize.height
    }
```

5. In your cellForItemAt set:

```swift
cell.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: I want a dynamic height cell, so in near future, I can add image view and other components.

Comment: I edited my question for the part about text. As regards the image check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185027/dynamically-sizing-uicollectionviewcell-dynamically-with-image-upload-swift

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`:

```
collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

After that change, I don't see any overlapping on the simulator

Comment: I don't want a self-sizing collectionView. I want a self-sizing collectionView Cell. if I return the fixed size in a sizeForItemAt method, how can it work?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it solved overlapping of Cell. but still scrolling is not smooth and content offset changed.